# Flutter: account-exists-with-different-credential after changing Facebook app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I was using a temporal Facebook app but today I moved to the final one with a different account so I had to change app ID and secret app ID from my flutter app.

I also modified these IDs from Firebase and downloaded again the `GoogleService-Info.plist`. The functionality and migration to the new app is working.

The problem is that many users created an account using the previous Facebook app and now, when they login they get this: `account-exists-with-different-credential`.

I had this fixed for Google/Facebook accounts doing something like this (for example a Facebook user already registered with Google):

```
if (signInMethods.first == 'google.com') {
   return await googleSignIn(context, email, credential);
}
```

So we would display the login with Google instead after trying with Facebook.

What's the problem now? That these old users are getting `facebook.com` and I cannot show again the Facebook login due to infinite loop.

For each user I have some info (name, email and picture) and some collections. How can I overwrite these info?